# Automatic Windows Service Not Starting

Tags: windows, service, windows-service

I have a services running in Windows Local Services which is set to Automatic Startup. Every so often this service doesn't start after a reboot and there are no errors in the event log.

The service uses a domain service account as its impersonation. I have a feeling that the machine is having difficulty communicating to the domain controller and verifiying the logon which could be preventing the service from starting.

Questions

Are service account credentials cached for service logons? What is the expected behaviour if the logon cannot be verified?

Answer (score 2):

No, the account credentials are not cached in this situation.

Comment: Thanks - What is the expected behaviour if the service cannot login? Does it simply not start? Should there be an error thrown?

Comment: Well I'm not sure about that, that's why I didn't answer that one. What is the service?

Answer (score 1):

Does your service have any dependencies? Perhaps it is starting too soon, before the key services that support networking (such as "Workstation" and "Network Connections") are fully initialized. Try setting your service to be dependent on these services and see if that solves the problem..

Another simpler alternative is to change your service's startup type to [Automatic (Delayed Start)](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#DelayedStart). This will have your service started 1-2 minutes after boot, giving the critical services sufficient time to get on their feet beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Windows Service Control Manager controls the state (i.e., started, stopped, paused, etc.) of all installed Windows services. By default, the Service Control Manager will wait 30,000 milliseconds (30 seconds) for a service to respond. Certain configurations, technical restrictions, or performance issues may result in the service taking longer than 30 seconds to start and report ready to the Service Control Manager.

By editing or creating the ServicesPipeTimeout DWORD value, the Service Control Manager timeout period can be overridden, thereby giving the service more time to start up and report ready to the service.

**How to make it ?**

1. Go to Start > Run > and type regedit
2. Navigate to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control
3. With the control folder selected, right click in the pane on the right and select new DWORD Value
4. Name the new DWORD: ServicesPipeTimeout
5. Right-click ServicesPipeTimeout, and then click Modify
6. Click Decimal, type '180000', and then click OK
7. Restart the computer

**Note:** The recommendation above increases the timeout to 180,000 milliseconds (3 minutes), but this may need to be increased further depending on your environment. Keep in mind that increasing this value will likely yield longer server boot times.